# How to overload the = in c++ in order to use it when creating an object?

Tags: c++

I have created a class that is meant to be initialized also with an initializer list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    A() = default;
    A(vector<int> values){
        a1 = values;
    }
    A& operator=( vector<int> values){
        a1 = values;
        return *this;
    }
    private:
    vector<int>a1;
};
```

When I do the first type of variable definition it won't give me errors:

```
int main() {
    A obj;
    obj={2,3,1,5,56,6,2};
    return 0;
}
```

However when I try the following I get this error:

```
int main() {
    A obj={2,3,1,5,56,6,2};
    return 0;
}
```

> error: could not convert '{2, 3, 1, 5, 56, 6, 2}' from 'brace-enclosed initializer list' to 'A'

Comment: *"I have created a class that is meant to be initialized also with an initializer list:"* -- and yet your functions do not take a `std::initializer_list<int>` parameter? The class is meant to be initialized with X, but initialization is defined to take Y instead? Something is off here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use initializer lists instead of vector in args. The following seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
  A() = default;
  A(initializer_list<int> values){ // <<<<<<<<<<<
    a1 = values;
  }
  A& operator=(initializer_list<int> values){ // <<<<<<<<<
    a1 = values;
    return *this;
  }
private:
  vector<int>a1;

};

int main() {
  A obj1 {2,3,1,5,56,6,2};
  A obj2;
  obj2={2,3,1,5,56,6,2};

  return 0;
}
```

You need c++11 or later.